# Input Validation on Sitecore Form Fields to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: security, sql-database

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` and the site is live.
We have forms on our site which have `radio button` and `text fields`.
The forms were created using `Sitecore Forms`.

We got few malicious submissions on our forms recently as shown below, hence, need to apply `input validation` on the form fields at the earliest to prevent `SQL injection`.

```
Comments (Text field) -  0"XOR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(15),0))XOR"Z
Ratings (1,2,3,4,5) -  (select(0)from(select(sleep(15)))v)/*'+(select(0)from(select(sleep(15)))v)+'"+(select(0)from(select(sleep(15)))v)+"*/
```

The user changed the form values  for radio button field using inspect element.
Are there any `out of the box validations` provided by sitecore that can help us prevent SQL injection?
Can anybody please provide some suggestions on implementing this for text and radio button fields?

Comment: This isn't Sitecore specific, but slapping these submissions down via WAF rules is a great option.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most of these types of attacks are executed using scripts that scrape the input fields and brute-force the form POST.  You might try using the built-in reCAPTCHA field to ensure the form is filled out by humans.

Here’s an article that may be helpful in implementing reCAPTCHA in Sitecore 9.3

https://sitecorescientist.com/2018/11/11/sitecore-9-forms-part-2-google-recaptcha-field/amp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have implemented this in our project and it works. But the hacker was trying to do SQL injection manually. Do you have any suggestions in that case?